# requestFeature() - where to put it when implementing custom title in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-titlebar

I got this exception when trying to implement a custom title of my dialogfragment

```
 requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

There are a lot of threads on stackoverflow about this but the problem is that I do not really know how to implement this functioncall AND where to put it?

I have tried to put it in the fragments callback onCreate() but it doesnt work at all.

So how should I use and put this functioncall? For instance - If I have created a custom title for my fragment - is it correct to use the following flag when calling requestFeature:

```
 Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE
```

?

```
public static class ImageExtrasFragment extends DialogFragment {

private View theView;       


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActivity().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //views
    theView = factory.inflate(R.layout.tex_timage, null);
    imgView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.text_img);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttitle, null);

    TextView titleView = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_title);
    titleView.setText(title);

    builder.setView(dialogView);
    return builder.create();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return theView;
}

}
```